# Custom line chart - the Gap between the vertical linear axis needs to be dynamic

Tags: apache-flex

I am stuck up with custom line chart. I need some help to move further.

The line chart looks like this

```
       100      |
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |      (90,x)
    90  |         *
        |
        |
        |
    50  |
        |
    10  |
        |
    0   ------------------------------------------
```

where the vertical axis, intervals needs to be variable, not evenly and the line chart should plot accordingly.
Can we achieve this ? I need some help.

Comment: How do you want to define the scale and function of the Y-Axis? Should it be fixed in code or is it a flexible property of the chart? Which functions would you like to implement for the Axis (log, x^2...)?

Comment: Hi...Thanks for reply..
the Scale should be flexible. i think we need to implement buildLabelCache() method to achieve this. I need some help to do this.

Comment: Let us discuss how you would specify the vertical axis. I would use a function to transform scale of the whole axis. It follows from your task, that you want be able to move any Y-point flexible without to define any function for the whole axis. Is it so? If so, write please which input values should your Y-Axis have to perform the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this what you are looking for what

[image]